# niether alert nor console working even the response in network is correct?

Tags: post, console, fetch-api, alert, httpresponse

I have created a fetch-api which is getting a response back 0 but and then I have written code inside then block which will alert but its not working I have changed it with console also still no error no console I have  checked network response also it is showing 0 preview also

I am expecting TO SHOW alert box if response is correct